# I have problem connecting to the internet after upgrading to ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS desktop version

Tags: networking

I have problem connecting to the internet after upgrading to ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS desktop version.

The system was installed in VirtualBox. It worked well before; after upgrading to 14.04.1 LTS, it cannot access the internet. The status says the VM is connected. However, when open the browser, it always says server not found.

I install a new 14.04.1 LTS desktop, instead of upgrading from an old one. The problem still exists.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try in settings of Virtualbox go to *Network* -> *Adapter 1* and change option *attached to* from **Nat** to **Bridged Adapter** then in *advanced* set *Promiscuous mode* to **allow VMs**

Comment: It is now always disconnected.